# PHP - file upload won't work on strato server

Tags: php, apache, web, file-upload

I have got some frustating problems facing file upload with a php script. The problem is that my script is working on my local xampp server. But when I transfer it to my strato host server it won't work anymore. There is no error output, although I have set display_errors to on and error_reporting to E_ALL.

Here is my complete code which I copied from the w3school file upload tutorial and is stored in the file upload.php:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "./uploads";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    print_r($_FILES);

    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (copy($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }       
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of the script after every submission is:

> Array ( ) File is not an image.Sorry, file already exists.Sorry, your
>   file was not uploaded.

As you can see the $_FILES array is completly empty.. no matter what type of file I upload.

I checked my php.ini and also phpinfo() for the relevant configuration parameters. This is what I got:

```
file_uploads = On;
memory_limit = 128M;
post_max_size = 128M;
upload_max_filesize = 128M;
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp;
```

The files I tried to upload of course did not exceed the limit of 128MB.

The script itself should not cause my problem, since it works on my local XAMPP server and for many other users and servers. There must be something wrong with my strato server configuration, but I can't figure out what the problem is. The php.ini seems wright. Does anybody have an idea, a clue or maybe just a hint?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you check if your server has Modsec module installed? A lot of times these security settings prevent file uploading.

Comment: @Rahi How can i find this out?

Comment: What control panel (cpanel, WHM etc) is available to you for server management? Assuming you have Cpanel access, there would be a module called ModSec under Security section.

Comment: ModSec ist not installed :(

Comment: Next step I'll recommend checking PHP suhosin extension. If it is installed update its value to allow PHP file upload and also file sizes etc. May be disable it first and then try uploading. 

Also, did you check your Apache and PHP error logs? Sometimes, php settings will write error log on the server in file names error_log rather printing it in the browser.