# strato php file upload

Tags: php, file-upload

I need help with my php file upload via **move_uploaded_file** statement on a **Strato** server. I use this simple [php upload script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) to upload a image to my strato webspace. But I receive this error message when uploading a image:

> Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Which is caused by an error in the **move_uploaded_file** method. Does anyone use this method on a Strato server successfully?

What I did so far is:

- set the rights of the folder uploads to 777 via chmod in FileZilla
- disabled the Server Side Spam Security (as the Strato support told me)
- disabled writing protection through the Site Guard Settings

Maybe there is also a way to get a better error message?

Comment: Oh and I saw this post already which does not lead to an anwer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747160/php-file-upload-wont-work-on-strato-server)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved my problem. It had a mistake in my upload path. Instead of using a relative path

```
$target_dir = "/uploads";
```

one needs the root of the server as addition:

```
$target_dir = __DIR__ . "/uploads";
```